# window.print() prints 6 empty pages before requested page

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a web page that contains a menu bar with 7 tabs. Right beneath the menu bar is a print button that calls the javascript window.prin() function. However, every time this button is pressed the pages for all 7 tabs get printed. Is there any way to specify exactly which page you want to print?

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="DistEducation.aspx.vb" Inherits="Periscope.DistEducation" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title>DistEducation</title>

    <%--Added the following three scripts for the TableSorter--%>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js"></script>  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jquery.tablesorter.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#grdTraining").tablesorter();
        });
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#grdExpTraining").tablesorter();
        });
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#grdProduct").tablesorter();
        });
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#grdExpProd").tablesorter();
        });

        function GridChanger() {
            var linker = document.getElementById("expTrainingShow");
            var grid = document.getElementById("expTraining");

            if ((grid != null) & (linker != null)) {
                if (linker.innerHTML == "+ Show Expired Continuing Education") {
                    grid.style.display = "block";
                    linker.innerHTML = "- Hide Expired Continuing Education";
                }
                else {
                    grid.style.display = "none";
                    linker.innerHTML = "+ Show Expired Continuing Education";
                }
            }

        } //end GridChanger

        function GridChangerProd() {
            var linker = document.getElementById("expProdShow");
            var grid = document.getElementById("expProd");

            if ((grid != null) & (linker != null)) {
                if (linker.innerHTML == "+ Show Expired Product Training") {
                    grid.style.display = "block";
                    linker.innerHTML = "- Hide Expired Product Training";
                }
                else {
                    grid.style.display = "none";
                    linker.innerHTML = "+ Show Expired Product Training";
                }
            }

        } //end GridChangerProd


        function doPrint() {
            window.print();
        }
    </script>

    <LINK href="../Stylesheets/Default.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <table width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td width="70%" align="left"></td>
                <td width="25%" align="right"><asp:label id="lblTime" Runat="server" CssClass="clsLabelStatus"></asp:label></td>
                <td width="5%" align="right"><input id="cmdPrint" title="Print" onclick="doPrint();" type="button" value="Print" name="cmdPrint"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    <div style="margin-left: 0px">
    <br />
<%--    <h2 style="background-position: center; background-color: #CCCCCC; font-family: Arial, Verdana, sans-serif; color: #000000; text-align: left; width: 100%;">Training and Continuing Education</h2>--%>
<%--        <asp:Label ID="TempMessage" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Large" 
            ForeColor="Red" Text="This tab will display Agent training in the near future."></asp:Label>--%>
        <h1 class="clsSectionBar" width: 100%;" 
            style="font-size: small; height: 20px; vertical-align: middle;">Continuing Education</h1>
        <asp:Label ID="UserMessage" runat="server" Text="" CssClass="clsLabel"></asp:Label>
        <br />
        <span id="expTrainingShow" class="clsLink" style="margin-left: 20px;" runat="server" onclick="GridChanger();">
            + Show Expired Continuing Education</span>


        <div id="expTraining" style="display:none;">
            <asp:GridView 
                AllowSorting="True"
                ID="grdExpTraining" 
                runat="server" BackColor="White" BorderColor="White" 
                BorderWidth="3px" CellPadding="2" Width="98%" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                HorizontalAlign="Center" Font-Names="Arial" 
                style="margin-top: 0px" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White">
                <RowStyle ForeColor="Black" />            
                <Columns>

                    <asp:BoundField DataField="StateCode" HeaderText="State" 
                        SortExpression="StateCode">
                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Top" Font-Size="Small" />
                    </asp:BoundField>

                    <asp:BoundField DataField="CourseDesc" HeaderText="Course" 
                        SortExpression="CourseDesc">
                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Top" Font-Size="Small" />
                    </asp:BoundField>

                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Hours" HeaderText="Hours" SortExpression="Hours">
                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Top" Font-Size="Small" />
                    </asp:BoundField>

                    <asp:BoundField DataField="EffectiveDate" HeaderText="Effective" 
                        SortExpression="EffectiveDate" DataFormatString="{0:d}">
                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Top" Font-Size="Small" />
                    </asp:BoundField>

                    <asp:BoundField DataField="ExpirationDate" HeaderText="Expiration" 
                        SortExpression="ExpirationDate" DataFormatString="{0:d}">
                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Top" Font-Size="Small" />
                    </asp:BoundField>

                <%--<asp:BoundField DataField="Notes" HeaderText="Notes" 
                        SortExpression="Notes">
                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Top" Font-Size="Small" Width="200" />
                    </asp:BoundField> Commented out until further notice (Neal Rodruck 7/26/12)--%>

                    <asp:BoundField DataField="LastChange" HeaderText="Last Chg"
                        SortExpression="LastChange" DataFormatString="{0:d}"> 
                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Top" Font-Size="Small" Width="145" />
                    </asp:BoundField>

                </Columns>
                <FooterStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#000066" />
                <PagerStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#000066" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#669999" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <HeaderStyle CssClass="clsListHeading" Font-Size="Small" />
            </asp:GridView>
        </div>

        <asp:GridView 
            AllowSorting="True"
            ID="grdTraining"  
            runat="server" BackColor="White" BorderColor="White" 
            BorderWidth="3px" CellPadding="2" Width="98%" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            HorizontalAlign="Center" Font-Names="Arial" 
            style="margin-top: 0px" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White" >
            <RowStyle ForeColor="Black" />            
            <Columns>

                <asp:BoundField DataField="StateCode" HeaderText="State" 
                    SortExpression="StateCode">
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Top" Font-Size="Small" />
                </asp:BoundField>

                <asp:BoundField DataField="CourseDesc" HeaderText="Course" 
                    SortExpression="CourseDesc">
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Top" Font-Size="Small" />
                </asp:BoundField>

                <asp:BoundField DataField="Hours" HeaderText="Hours" SortExpression="Hours">
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Top" Font-Size="Small" />
                </asp:BoundField>

                <asp:BoundField DataField="EffectiveDate" HeaderText="Effective" 
                    SortExpression="EffectiveDate" DataFormatString="{0:d}">
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Top" Font-Size="Small" />
                </asp:BoundField>

                <asp:BoundField DataField="ExpirationDate" HeaderText="Expiration" 
                    SortExpression="ExpirationDate" DataFormatString="{0:d}">
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Top" Font-Size="Small" />
                </asp:BoundField>

            <%--<asp:BoundField DataField="Notes" HeaderText="Notes" 
                    SortExpression="Notes">
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Top" Font-Size="Small" Width="200" />
                </asp:BoundField> Commented out until further notice (Neal Rodruck 7/26/12)--%>

                <asp:BoundField DataField="LastChange" HeaderText="Last Chg"
                    SortExpression="LastChange" DataFormatString="{0:d}"> 
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Top" Font-Size="Small" Width="145" />
                </asp:BoundField>

            </Columns>
            <FooterStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#000066" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#000066" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#669999" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <HeaderStyle CssClass="clsListHeading" Font-Size="Small" />
        </asp:GridView>
        <br />
        <h1 class="clsSectionBar" width: 100%;" 
            style="font-size: small; height: 20px; vertical-align: middle;" 
            id="prodInfo" >Product Training</h1>
        <asp:Label ID="ProductMessage" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
        <br />

                <span id="expProdShow" class="clsLink" style="margin-left: 20px;" runat="server" onclick="GridChangerProd();">
            + Show Expired Product Training</span>

        <div id="expProd" style="display:none;">
            <asp:GridView 
                AllowSorting="True"
                ID="grdExpProd"
                runat="server" BackColor="White" BorderColor="White" 
                BorderWidth="3px" CellPadding="2" Width="98%" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                HorizontalAlign="Center" Font-Names="Arial" 
                style="margin-top: 0px" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White">
                <RowStyle ForeColor="Black" />            
                <Columns>

                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Partner" HeaderText="Partner"
                        SortExpression="Partner">
                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Top" Font-Size="Small" />
                    </asp:BoundField>

                    <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductDesc" HeaderText="Product"
                        SortExpression ="ProductDesc">
                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Top" Font-Size="Small" />
                    </asp:BoundField>

                    <asp:BoundField DataField="DateTaken" HeaderText="Date Taken" 
                        SortExpression="DateTaken" DataFormatString="{0:d}">
                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Top" Font-Size="Small" />
                    </asp:BoundField>

                    <asp:BoundField DataField="DateExpired" HeaderText="Date Expired" 
                        SortExpression="DateExpired" DataFormatString="{0:d}">
                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Top" Font-Size="Small" />
                    </asp:BoundField>

                    <asp:BoundField DataField="CourseDesc" HeaderText="Course"
                        SortExpression="CourseDesc">
                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Top" Font-Size="Small" />
                    </asp:BoundField>

                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Status" HeaderText="Status" 
                        SortExpression="Status" >
                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Top" Font-Size="Small" />
                    </asp:BoundField>

                </Columns>
                <FooterStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#000066" />
                <PagerStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#000066" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#669999" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <HeaderStyle CssClass="clsListHeading" Font-Size="Small" />
            </asp:GridView></div>

        <asp:GridView 
            AllowSorting="True"
            ID="grdProduct"  
            runat="server" BackColor="White" BorderColor="White" 
            BorderWidth="3px" CellPadding="2" Width="98%" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            HorizontalAlign="Center" Font-Names="Arial" 
            style="margin-top: 0px" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White" >
            <RowStyle ForeColor="Black" />
            <Columns>

                <asp:BoundField DataField="Partner" HeaderText="Partner"
                    SortExpression="Partner">
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Top" Font-Size="Small" />
                </asp:BoundField>

                <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductDesc" HeaderText="Product"
                    SortExpression ="ProductDesc">
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Top" Font-Size="Small" />
                </asp:BoundField>

                <asp:BoundField DataField="DateTaken" HeaderText="Date Taken" 
                    SortExpression="DateTaken" DataFormatString="{0:d}">
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Top" Font-Size="Small" />
                </asp:BoundField>

                <asp:BoundField DataField="DateExpired" HeaderText="Date Expired" 
                    SortExpression="DateExpired" DataFormatString="{0:d}">
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Top" Font-Size="Small" />
                </asp:BoundField>

                <asp:BoundField DataField="CourseDesc" HeaderText="Course"
                    SortExpression="CourseDesc">
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Top" Font-Size="Small" />
                </asp:BoundField>

                <asp:BoundField DataField="Status" HeaderText="Status" 
                    SortExpression="Status" >
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Top" Font-Size="Small" />
                </asp:BoundField>

            </Columns>
            <FooterStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#000066" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#000066" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#669999" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <HeaderStyle CssClass="clsListHeading" Font-Size="Small" />
        </asp:GridView>
         &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This HTML is "all the code"? Because you can't say "automatically" what page print, you need to work with css to find a good solution, to do this is necessary see your entire HTML code.

Comment: Consider using a `print` stylesheet to hide the menu bars and extra pages.

Comment: width = 100% is relative to the parent's size. We need to see the entire html to see why you are getting so many pages printed out.

Comment: just added the full html/javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my application, I used the pop up window to print the portion of the page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#printButton').click(function () {
            PrintElement($('#mainContent'));
        });
    });

    var PrintElement = function (element) {
        Popup($(element).html());
    }
    var Popup = function (data) {
        var mywindow = window.open('', 'print_div', 'resizable=1,scrollbars=1,height=400,width=600');
        mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title>Print Window</title><link href="../../Includes/Styles/Global.css" type="text/css" rel="Stylesheet" />');
        mywindow.document.write('</head><body><div id="mainMasterDiv">');
        mywindow.document.write(data);
        mywindow.document.getElementById("printButton").style.display = "none";
        mywindow.document.write('</div></body></html>');
        mywindow.document.close();
        mywindow.print();
        return true;
    }
</script>
```

Once user click on print button, I pass the resultDetailsDiv to PrintElement function, which opens a popup with same content, prints it and closes it.
Only thing i have to include the css using javascript to maintain the layout and style of div content.
The Popup function is written in Javascript, You can try writing the function in Jquery, which can reduce your code lines.

The  printButton is the button which prints, and mainContent is the div which has the content to be printed.

Comment: I'm very new to JavaScript. Is the printButton the name of you button? If so how do you specify that this function gets called?

Comment: Yes printButton is the id of print button, i changed the code to get by Jquery. This is workable code, you can replace your print button id and mainContent div id.

Comment: Thank you. One last question, do you need to put anything in the button's onlcick= section?

Comment: not required, we are already binding it using jquery, if it gives some problem you can unbind first:
$('#printButton').unbind('click').bind('click',function () {
                PrintElement($('#mainContent'));
            });